# Numpy error on Google Cloud Functions which does not happen locally

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Below google cloud function runs fine locally but fails when deployed on the cloud.

```
from flask import escape
import functions_framework
import numpy as np

@functions_framework.http
def test_func(request):
    np_array = np.zeros(172128250, dtype=np.complex64)
    print('np_array shape: ', np_array.shape)
    abs_array = np.abs(np_array)
    print('abs_array shape: ', abs_array.shape)
    return 'Hello World'
```

Python versions tried: *3.7, 3.8, and 3.9*.

Timeout: 540s

Memory: 8GB

np_array is successfully created but it fails to compute abs. Function prints first log `np_array shape: (172128250,)` but fails to print the second log. The functions exits abruptly printing `Function execution took 2408 ms, finished with status: 'connection error'`. It works for all the sizes locally, but on the cloud, it specifically fails for the NumPy array of the following 10 sizes `[172128241, 172128242, ..., 172128250]`.

Comment: Don't you have other logs? It's strange...

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes, I see one warning. `OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system, assuming 256k`. Actually, this error occurred when some `librosa` function internally calls `np.abs`. After multiple iterations of debugging, I got to these two lines of code. Initially, np_array was a 2D of dimensions `1025 * 167930`

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere , I have a feeling that it is due to some memory allocation issue on the cloud. I found six more ranges of size 10 for which it fails `{172127217, ..., 172127226}, {172127217..172127226}, {172126193..172126202}, {172125169..172125178}, {172124145..172124154}, {172123121..172123130}`. Please note the difference between these ranges is exactly `1024`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the error occurs with Numpy version: `1.19.4` on the cloud. After using `1.21.5` on the cloud, the error goes away. It's still strange why it works locally with `1.19.4` but fails on the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Your execution environment is sandboxed and you can't get some CPU features (for more details, have a look to [gVisor project](https://github.com/google/gvisor)).

To solve that, I can recommend you to switch to Cloud Run (simply wrap your code in a web server, see my [old article here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-and-cloud-function-what-i-use-and-why-12bb5d3798e1)) and use [execution runtime gen2](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#sandbox) (still in preview)

Comment: I have my reasons for using google cloud functions. Can you please confirm that this is due to some bug in the google cloud functions and it should have worked?

Comment: It's not a bug. Anyway, what's your reason to use Cloud Functions? There is no (or very very very few and specific) difference with Cloud Run!

Comment: Got it to work with another NumPy version. If I face some more errors, I will check if cloud run fixes that. Thanks for your help.